# WPF ComboBox Text property blank with ItemTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, itemtemplate

I have a ComboBox which uses an ItemTemplate consisting of a CheckBox and a TextBlock.  My goal is that when items are checked/unchecked, the collapsed combobox displays a comma-separated list of the items that are checked.  I thought the Text property of the ComboBox could be used for this purpose, but this is only enabled when IsEditable = true, otherwise it is just blank even when bound to a property.  I don't want the combo to be editable.

It would be nice if I could provide some sort of simple template to display a property consisting of checked items from the list.  Is this possible?

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Issues}" Text="{Binding IssuesCSV}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="4 0 4 0" 
                          IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Issue.Number}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: try here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45782/A-WPF-Combo-Box-with-Multiple-Selection , it might give a direction

Answer (score 0):

Your desired behavior is different enough from a ComboBox that you might want to consider building yourself a custom control.

But... I think there *is* a way to get what you want from a ComboBox

First, create a VisualBrush resource and bind it to your IssuesCSV value:

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="TextBrush" TileMode="None" Opacity="0.4" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IssuesCSV}"/>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>
```

Then, set the background property of your ComboBox to use that brush resource:

```
<ComboBox ... Background="{StaticResource TextBrush}" ... />
```

Then, set the ComboBox to be editable, but read-only. This will keep the silver default styling of the non-editable ComboBox from covering up your text during drop down: (You could also probably play with the ComboBox style to achieve this while keeping the ComboBox truly non-editable)

```
<ComboBox ... IsReadOnly="True" IsEditable="True" ... />
```

Finally, prevent the user from being able to actually select a ComboBoxItem by providing a handler for the SelectionChanged event, which simply sets the SelectedItem back to null:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectionChanged="myCB_SelectionChanged" ... />

private void myCB_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   myCB.SelectedItem = null;
}
```